# Is Sulfur or Sulfur Dioxide harmful to the environment?

Tags: environmental-chemistry

I'm studying the impact/effects of greenhouse gases/pollution on the environment. I found that sulfur dioxide has [harmful effects](https://www.epa.gov/so2-pollution/sulfur-dioxide-basics#:%7E:text=At%20high%20concentrations%2C%20gaseous%20SOx,which%20can%20harm%20sensitive%20ecosystems.) , but I read [here](https://smartairfilters.com/learn/smart-air-knowledge-base/does-air-pollution-some-advantages/) that "pollutants like sulfur actually keep our planet cooler." So, I wanted to know, what's the difference between the two? And which one is the true greenhouse gas? Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference and no two. Sulfur in the quotation is actually supposed to mean _"sulfur dioxide"_. OK, to be more precise: _"sulfur dioxide and a few other unimportant compounds"_.

Comment: In the absence of citations in your second link I would ignore information in it. Rely on more reliable sources, for instance EPA.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @Ivan's comment, the sulfur in that quotation pretty much meant other sulfur oxides ($\ce{SO_x}$). If it was to mean elemental sulfur, then it would interact with the environment in its in vapor state but sulfur vapor only exist at very high temperatures which is beyond even earth's recorded highest temperature.

While sulfur dioxide isn’t a direct greenhouse gas like carbon dioxide or methane, it is considered an indirect greenhouse gas because, when coupled with elemental carbon, it forms [aerosols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosol). Also, it is a no-brainer that $\ce{SO_x}$ is very deadly as it poses the threat of forming [acid rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain).

Comment: (+1) All the more amazing that people mine big blocks of sulfur at the active volcano named Kawah Ijen, in East Java, Indonesia. At night, the sulfur burns blue, making for an eerily beautiful but toxic spectacle. Wild and crazy planet we got here! ;-)